# How to delete a single row from the table on clicking the icon/button

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

I am using **Table with pagination** component in my project.I need to delete the single row at a time on clicking the **delete** icon. Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7mmie) link i have created.

Tried this [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a7mmie),here they have performed edit | update | delete operations.I want only delete operation.How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Create a `delete` function like so:

```
delete(elm) {
  this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data.filter(i => i !== elm)
}
```

And call it from the HTML:

```
              <ng-container matColumnDef="columndelete">
                <th style="width:15%;" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> </th>
                <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">       
                  <mat-icon (click)="delete(element)">delete</mat-icon> </td>
              </ng-container>
```

**[Here is a fork of the StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y5de69?file=src/app/table-delete/table-delete.component.html)**

**EDIT**

If you don't need to udpate the value of position, you can use:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element; let idx = index"> {{ idx + 1 }}
```

On the cell. This will display the correct value, but leave position unchanged.

If you want to change the position value as well, you can use:

```
   this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data
      .filter(i => i !== elm)
      .map((i, idx) => (i.position = (idx + 1), i)); // Update the position
```

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: If this helped, please mark it as accepted with the green tick so that others can more easily find the solution. Thanks

Comment: Ya surely i will mark, still i need to wait for 6 min. To mark as correct.

Comment: Its deleting entire row that is fine, How to keep the numerical order properly after deleting the row i,e serial number(Sl no).

Comment: @PrashanthHiremath So if you delete #4, then the old #5 should become #4 and so on?

Comment: Ya exactly it should happen like your comment.

Comment: @PrashanthHiremath I;ve updated the answer and stackblitz for you

Comment: ya i got it, You saved my day.

Comment: For who wants to avoid comma operator. use this,     this.dataSource.data = this.dataSource.data
      .filter(i => i !== element)
      .map((i, idx) => {
        i.id = (idx + 1);
        return i;
      });